# How to disable Google Cloud Platform integration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have these two dependencies in my POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'd like to disable these GCP features in certain profiles. I need to test my app locally but GCP keeps getting in the way.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Can you not remove them from your POM?  What happens if you try?  Can you clarify what it means to say "GCP keeps getting in the way"?

Comment: The application cannot start if these two dependencies are present using the local profile. If these dependencies are present it thinks its in the gcp environment. i'd like to turn them off while developing locally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring depends on auto-configuration when setting up the application. In many cases, it scans the classpath for certain dependencies, and if they are present, auto-configuration is performed. Most of the times the auto-configuration can be bypassed by providing a certain conditional.

While traversing the Spring cloud gcp modules I came across the `StackdriverLoggingAutoConfiguration` class ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/logging/StackdriverLoggingAutoConfiguration.html)) and `StackdriverTraceAutoConfiguration` ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/trace/StackdriverTraceAutoConfiguration.html)).

StackdriverLoggingAutoConfiguration has the conditional `ConditionalOnProperty(value="spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled", matchIfMissing=true)`, while StackdriverTraceAutoConfiguration has the conditional `@ConditionalOnProperty(value="spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled", matchIfMissing=true)`

I'm not entirely sure if the properties are related to the auto-configuration of the modules you use, but you migh be able to disable the logging by adding the following to your application-{localprofile}.properties:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled=false
spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled=false
```

Comment: I have tried doing that without success. I also tried `spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled=false` which produced less errors.

Comment: The `StackdriverLoggingAutoConfiguration` contains another annotation; `@AutoConfigureAfter(value=StackdriverTraceAutoConfiguration.class)` . 

Auto-configuration classes can be excluded using the property `spring.autoconfigure.exclude`:

`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.trace.StackdriverTraceAutoConfiguration`.

Does that work in your scenario?

Comment: Still cannot disable the default credential, got same error: `The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.`

Comment: I had the same issue and unfortunately could not succeed without a workaround. To exclude the autoconfiguration class: `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.storage.GcpStorageAutoConfiguration`

Answer (score 6):

Because the question is

> How to disable Google Cloud Platform integration

I would suggest to just change our configuration with

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      core:
        enabled: false
```

It should be enough to disable everything related to Spring Cloud GCP in our project

The accepted answer tells you how to disable a part of the GCP feature used in our project. If you have many of them (logging, PubSub, Storage, ...) it can be cumbersome to disable all of them. This is a shortcut to disable all of them at once ;-)

Comment: This will disable everything from GCP, even we just use Firebase one and that lead to compile error on auto configure too. If disable like that, why not exclude them from dependency instead?

Comment: It can be useful for local development for instance. When you do not want to connect to GCP and have alternative implementation that can do the job. For instance, if I use Pub/Sub and locally I do not want to use it, the class that will send the message could have 2 implementations. One that really send the message to GCP and the other one that just logs it. That way I can still develop locally and do not need to have GCP credentials on my computer...

Comment: even with this option, I have a message saying: `Parameter 1 of constructor in com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.core.GcpProjectIdProvider' that could not be found.` . Then it seems not enough

Comment: and after even with disabling my pubsub conf, as the bean does not exists, my app fails to start because PubSub bean is not created.
There should be a way to inject a mock object instead the real conf.

Answer (score 2):

you can disable tracing,, logging and provide a fake id as follow:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=fake-project-id
spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled=false
spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled=false
```

Comment: Still got the same error: `The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable gcp pubsud, you need to add 
spring.cloud.gcp.core.enabled=false 
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.enabled=false

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32232370)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old but you also can disable the AutoConfiguration classes by annotation.

For exemple :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.class})
```

I hope than can help someone one day :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a food for thought.

In case you are building an application, that can work in different environments (like in my case - locally, or on GCP with GCP resources) - just avoid using `spring-cloud-gcp-starter` whatsoever.

There is no way to `properly` manage your app's lifecycle with these, as they are all statically-initialized, and always work either in GCP-mode, or without it. That's it.

Instead, I propose to consinder building your own `GcpFileProvider`, or `gcp-whatever-provider` using good old Google libraries (f.e. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries), NOT `spring-starter` libraries.

This approach:

1. Saves you the pain of managing these configurations anyhow except of **just using them WHEN you need them**.
2. Saves you from hacking your way trough these static-inits this way or another (totally doable, but imho doesn't worth the efforts, and results in very complicated setup for really simple things).
3. Gives you an option to switch Providers on-the-fly, if required.

Last bullet can actually be a good help in integration testing.

P.S. All the convenience of "*I just want it to work OOB on GCP*" work flawlessly with these google-libraries, as they do with spring.

Small example for GCP Bucket reader, that optimistically gets available credentials when initializing, same as spring-libs do:

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage'

}
```

Provider:

```java
import com.google.cloud.storage.*;

...
    // .getDefaultInstance() actually does all the bootstrap for GCP services that you might need.
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    Blob blob = getStorage().get(BlobId.of(bucketName, itemSubPathAndName));
    ReadChannel reader = blob.reader();
    InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(reader);
...
```

And then, in my tests I can easily switch profiles on-the-fly, and even make sure that integration tests are running only if GCP configuration is available, and valid:

Generic/Local:

```java
...
@ActiveProfiles("localResources")
...
public class SomeLocalOrGenericTests {
...
}
```

GCP/Integration:

```java
...
@ActiveProfiles("gcpResources")
...
public class SomeIntegrationTest {
...
    private Boolean gcpCredsAreValid = false;
    @BeforeAll
    public void setup() {
        var project = "UNKNOWN";
        try {
            project = ((UserCredentials) GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()).getQuotaProjectId();
            if (!project.isEmpty() && !project.contains("test")  && !project.equals("UNKNOWN")) {
                gcpCredsAreValid = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, String.format("gcpCredsAreValid is false. ProjectID is: %s%n", project));
        }
    }

    // And then

    @Test
    public void testingThatSomethingIsAvailableAtGcpBucket() {
        Assumptions.assumeTrue(gcpCredsAreValid, "Skipping GCP tests as GCP credentials are invalid");
        // Actual test of integrations, that will reliably run only if GCP is configured, and available
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works add to my test source code test configuration:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.google.api.gax.core.CredentialsProvider;
import com.google.auth.Credentials;

@TestConfiguration
public class TestGcpConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider() throws IOException {
        Credentials mockCredentials = mock(Credentials.class);
        CredentialsProvider mockCredentialsProvider = mock(CredentialsProvider.class);
        when(mockCredentialsProvider.getCredentials()).thenReturn(mockCredentials);
        return mockCredentialsProvider;
    }
}
```